Not able to show significant difference in my plot
Using my code below I plotted a violin plot. I am also trying to apply Games-Howell ANOVA post-hoc test on my data. Which is successfully completing and showing significant difference between A, B, C and D subgenomes. However, I am not able to show significant difference in my plot. Only the last part of my code needs to fixed I think # Annotate significant difference.
Anova post-hoc test shows the following significance. All I am trying is to plot this significance *** between A and B, A and C, A and D.
Comparison between treatments means
    difference pvalue signif.          LCL         UCL

A - B -0.037101857 0.0000     *** -0.046188341 -0.02801537
A - C -0.028211022 0.0000     *** -0.037394783 -0.01902726
A - D -0.030163234 0.0000     *** -0.039466699 -0.02085977
B - C  0.008890835 0.1059         -0.001186665  0.01896834
B - D  0.006938623 0.2979         -0.003248084  0.01712533
C - D -0.001952212 0.9618         -0.012225785  0.00832136
I tried adjusting the ymax limit but I am getting this warning message:
Warning messages:
1: Removed 1 row containing missing values or values outside the scale range
(`geom_text()`). 
2: Removed 1 row containing missing values or values outside the scale range
(`geom_text()`). 
3: Removed 1 row containing missing values or values outside the scale range
(`geom_text()`). 

my code:
library(dplyr)
library(agricolae)
library(stringr)
library(ggplot2)
library(Hmisc)

# Read the data
df <- read.table('ABCD-meth-r1.tsv', header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
df$subgenome <- factor(df$subgenome)

#create myxlab label
my_xlab <- paste(levels(df$subgenome), "\n ",table(df$subgenome),sep="")

#Conduct ANOVA
anova_result <- aov(value ~ subgenome, data = df)
summary(anova_result)

# Initialize sig_diff as a data frame to avoid scoping issues if no significant results
sig_diff <- data.frame(group1 = character(), group2 = character(), pvalue = numeric())

# Check if the ANOVA is significant and then perform Games-Howell test
if (summary(anova_result)[[1]][["Pr(>F)"]][1] < 0.05) {
    print("Significant differences detected, performing Games-Howell test")
    games_howell_result <- HSD.test(anova_result, "subgenome", group=FALSE, console=TRUE)

# Extracting pairs with significant differences
if (nrow(games_howell_result$comparison) > 0) {
    sig_diff <- games_howell_result$comparison[games_howell_result$comparison$pvalue < 
    0.05,]
       }
    }

# Calculate ymax
ymax <- max(df$value, na.rm = TRUE) * 1.1
print(paste("ymax for annotation:", ymax))

# Plotting code
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = subgenome, y = value, fill = subgenome)) +
      geom_violin() + 
      geom_boxplot(width=0.08, fill="white")+
      stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="point", shape=20, size=1, color="darkgreen") +
      scale_x_discrete(labels=my_xlab)+
      xlab("") +
      ylab("CDS methylation") +
      theme_bw()
      ylim(0, ymax)

# Annotate significant differences
if (nrow(sig_diff) > 0) {
    for(i in 1:nrow(sig_diff)) {
        sub1_index <- which(levels(df$subgenome) == sig_diff$group1[i])
        sub2_index <- which(levels(df$subgenome) == sig_diff$group2[i])
        mid_x <- mean(c(sub1_index, sub2_index))
        print(paste("Annotating between:", sig_diff$group1[i], "and", sig_diff$group2[i], 
    "at", mid_x))
        p <- p + annotate("text", label = "*", x = mid_x, y = ymax * 0.95, size = 5, 
    vjust = 0)
        p <- p + annotate("segment", x = sub1_index, xend = sub2_index, y = ymax, yend = 
    ymax, color = "red", linewidth = 1)
    }
}

# Print the plot
print(p)

Output plot:

  made the following change in the last line of the part of code. 
  Rest everything stay the same:
  # Plotting code
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = subgenome, y = value, fill = subgenome)) +
  geom_violin() + 
  geom_boxplot(width=0.08, fill="white")+
  stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="point", shape=20, size=1, color="darkgreen") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=my_xlab)+
  xlab("") +
  ylab("CDS methylation") +
  theme_bw()+
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, ymax), clip = "off")

Made the foolowing change in the plot:
# Initialize sig_diff as a data frame to avoid scoping issues if no significant results
sig_diff <- data.frame(group1 = character(), group2 = character(), pvalue = numeric())
**sig_diff$group2 <- sub(".+ \\- (.+)", "\\1", row.names(sig_diff))
sig_diff$group1 <- sub("(.+) \\- .+", "\\1", row.names(sig_diff))**



I think you missed a + before ylim(). Also you could replace ylim() with a coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, ymax), clip = "off")

with coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, ymax), clip = "off") same warning messages and the plot is unchanged.

Hmm, the warning definitely seems to be something with the default behavior of removing values that don't fall on the panel. And since you don't include a limits argument in your scales, the zoom in with coord_cartesian(clip = "off") has not interfered in my experience annotating p-values like this. Happy to help if you have a subset of data or example data to share. Perhaps you could try to manually add an annotation value first with hard values first.

Oh it looks like from the code you posted you may not have created sig_diff$group1 and sig_diff$group2 in the result dataframe. Might need something like sig_diff$group1 <- sub("(.+) \\- .+", "\\1", row.names(sig_diff)) and sig_diff$group2 <- sub(".+ \\- (.+)", "\\1", row.names(sig_diff))

Only the plot size and dimension changed but the significance level still not depicted in the plot @knitz3

Made a few changes and it worked. Had to be careful with setting ymax. Included some spacing between the bars. Did you fix the data frame at the right spot? I used some made up data here.
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(agricolae)

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  subgenome = factor(c(rep("A", 250), rep("B", 250), rep("C", 250), rep("D", 250))),
  value = sample(x = 1:100000, size = 1000) / 100000
)
head(df)
#   subgenome   value
# 1         A 0.51663
# 2         A 0.57870
# 3         A 0.02986
# ...
xlabels <- paste0(levels(df$subgenome), "\n", table(df$subgenome))

anova_result <- aov(value ~ subgenome, data = df)
games_howell_result <- HSD.test(anova_result, "subgenome", group = FALSE, console = TRUE)
# 0.85 for this dummy example
sig_diff <- games_howell_result$comparison[games_howell_result$comparison$pvalue < 0.85, ]
sig_diff$group1 <- sub("(.+) \\- .+", "\\1", row.names(sig_diff))
sig_diff$group2 <- sub(".+ \\- (.+)", "\\1", row.names(sig_diff))
sig_diff
#       difference pvalue signif.         LCL        UCL group1 group2
# A - B 0.02266492 0.8184         -0.04407579 0.08940563      A      B
# A - C 0.02760976 0.7112         -0.03913095 0.09435047      A      C
# A - D 0.02409436 0.7893         -0.04264635 0.09083507      A      D

ymax <- max(df$value, na.rm = TRUE)
# [1] 0.99889

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = subgenome, y = value, fill = subgenome)) +
  geom_violin() +
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.08, fill = "white") +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "point", shape = 20, size = 1, color = "darkgreen") +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("CDS methylation") +
  theme_bw()
  
# space between segments
sb <- 0.1 # starting value

if (nrow(sig_diff) > 0) {
  for (i in seq_along(row.names(sig_diff))) {
    sub1_index <- which(levels(df$subgenome) == sig_diff$group1[i])
    sub2_index <- which(levels(df$subgenome) == sig_diff$group2[i])
    mid_x <- mean(c(sub1_index, sub2_index))
    print(paste(
      "Annotating between:", sig_diff$group1[i], "and", sig_diff$group2[i],
      "at", mid_x
    ))
    p <- p + annotate("text", label = "*",
      x = mid_x, y = ymax + sb, size = 5, vjust = 0
    )
    p <- p + annotate("segment", color = "red", linewidth = 1,
      x = sub1_index,  xend = sub2_index,
      y = ymax + sb, yend = ymax + sb
    )
    # Add space
    sb <- sb + 0.15
  }
}
# [1] "Annotating between: A and B at 1.5"
# [1] "Annotating between: A and C at 2"
# [1] "Annotating between: A and D at 2.5"

p + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, ymax + sb), expand = FALSE, clip = "off")


Above puts the annotations in the plotting area, but you could also get them above by setting the ylim lower, including the clip = "off", and including a large top margin:
p +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, ymax), expand = FALSE, clip = "off") +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, unit = "in"))


